# When I define a backbone view does the view element have to be loaded into the DOM?

Tags: backbone.js, amd

I have some code which defines a backbone view being loaded as soon as a web page is loaded. The JavaScript is possibly executed before the DOM is fully loaded. If the dom element which becomes $el is not available when the code that defines the view is run is this a problem?

Programmatically I have something like this:

```
var view = Backbone.View.extend({
        el: jQuery("#test")

    events: {
    }
    render: function() {
        this.$el.html();
    }

   //other view code

});

return view;
```

//some time passes
//with the view rendered above I now call :

```
view.render()
```

the problem is that when the render method is called this.$el is undefined. This is because when the first block of code was executed #test had not been loaded into the DOM. So; when the function Backbone.View.extend is called the 'el' element has to be loaded?

The context of this is a backbone application loaded via AMD. The first block of code is in a module. The module is 'required' before the DOM is loaded. Is this a common problem? How is it normally dealt with?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

el should not be a jQuery object but only a selector, $el will be the jQuery object for that selector. Also the id you specify as the el has to be found at initialization. So yes, the element has to be in the dom before you make it the el for the view.

If you're not creating / populating the view before making it a Backbone view you could do something like this to have backbone create the html tags etc. for you:

```
var view = Backbone.View.extend({
    tagName: 'div',
    id: 'test',

    events: {
    },

    render: function() {
        this.$el.html();
    },

    //other view code

});
```

You could then use templates to populate the view in your render function.

Short answer: Yes, the view element has to be loaded into the DOM when you initialize the view.

Comment: Thanks. That's a bit clearer. I also saw that you can do set it by passing it to the constructor: var view = new View({ el: $("#search_container") }); But. Again; the element has to exist.